# how can you cache results in java without using Spring/Grails framework?

Tags: caching, grails, static-methods, java-threads

I have a pretty vague understaning in this: I have a web application in groovy thay uses Grails framework. There are multiple clients that use this application. When calling the same method by different users they obtain let's say different data. How? for each client is there a different thread created? I think not because there are hundred of clients and the production machine sure doesn't have hundred cores, so I must be some Grails magic I would like to read about. Any suggestions?

Also I noticed that there are static methods in the application and people say they cache the results? In my mind caching means that once you store something in the cache you don't call the cached method again. Please help me understand better these things.

Comment: For the second question (the one from the title) I found an example on how to do it: you have a static class that has a static field and you are initializing the field at class level and you have a static method where you check if the field is empty: if it is, you populate it, if not (it is already populated) you just return it. I just wonder when the initializaing occurs since it is a static class( eg: private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using standard Grails with no changes in filters or interceptors, then it does controls the sessions through cookies.

If you want a real stateless application (no controls about the user session) then you have to do some changes to the grails interceptors.

Besides, if you want to simply ignore the sessions that Grails natively manages then yes, creating a static workaround would do your thing. Even though, I would use ConcurrentHashMap to manage sessions that way (because concurrent threads would use your static variable).

```
def sessionMap = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap();
```

Take a look at:

https://github.com/kaleidos/grails-security-stateless/blob/master/README.md

or

https://www.slideshare.net/alvarosanchezmariscal/stateless-authentication-for-microservices (starting at slide 60)